# why is E(XX') the covariance matrix

Tags: matrices, regression, covariance

In regression people often refer to the $X'X$ term as the estimate of $E(xx')$ which makes sense by LLN. However, people also refer to $E(xx')$ as the covariance matrix of $x$ which only seems to make sense if $E(x)=0$. Why does it makes sense if the $x$'s are not demeaned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, the covariance of a random matrix $X$ is given by $E[(X-EX)(X-EX)']$, however note that in a context of regression analysis we are interested, inter alia, in the variance of the coefficients estimators. Consider a model $Y=X\beta + \epsilon$, with $var(\epsilon) = \sigma^2I$.
\begin{align}
var(\hat{\beta}|X)&=var((X'X)^{-1}X'y|X)\\
 &= (X'X)^{-1}X'var(y|X)X(X'X)^{-1}\\
 &= (X'X)^{-1}X'E(\epsilon\epsilon')X(X'X)^{-1}\\
 & = \sigma^2(X'X)^{-1}XX(X'X)^{-1}=\sigma^2 (X'X)^{-1}.  
\end{align}

Comment: yes, this is true. i just want to be sure that when people say var-covar matrix of X, they are really referring to var-covar matrix of $\beta$. the other thought i had was that having a constant in the regression is the same thing as simply center $x$ and $y$ so wanted to make sure there wasn't something i was missing. thanks!